# Reduce the icon size on an Android laptop running on Remix OS

Tags: app-icons, remix-os

I have recently dual booted Remix OS with Windows 10 on my Lenovo G580 and the problem is that the icons and the taskbar looks so big.

How to make them smaller?

Note- I am using UEFI mode

Answer (score 0):

You can change the DPI.

When booting, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd> to change the parameters of booting, and add

```
DPI=<Integer number>
```

In my case, I used 120 and got smaller icons, but you can try different numbers.